# JPA Map ManyToOne Relation with IdClass - persistence.ArgumentException

Tags: java, exception, jpa

I want to map two classes with a manyToOne /oneToMay relation with Apache OpenJPA 2.2.0.
One classe has a primary key of two attributes:

```
@Entity(name = "Player")
@IdClass(PlayerId.class)
public class Player {
    @Id
    private String nickname;
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;

    public Player() {

    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

}

public class PlayerId {
    private String nickname;
    private Team team;

    public PlayerId() {
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public Team getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(Team team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return ((o instanceof PlayerId) && 
                this.nickname == ((PlayerId)o).getNickname() &&
                this.team == ((PlayerId) o).getTeam());
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return nickname.hashCode() + team.hashCode();
    }
}

@Entity(name = "Team")
public class Team {
    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "team", targetEntity = Player.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Player> players;

    public Team() {

    }

    public List<Player> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    public void setPlayers(List<Player> p) {
        players = p;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So When I create a new Player with a team I get the follwing exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Errors encountered while resolving metadata.  See nested exceptions for details.
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:668)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:411)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:384)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolveMeta(MetaDataRepository.java:714)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:643)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:411)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:384)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.getMapping(MappingRepository.java:355)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.getMapping(MappingTool.java:682)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.buildSchema(MappingTool.java:754)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.run(MappingTool.java:652)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:164)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newBrokerImpl(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The id class specified by type "class model.Player" does not match the primary key fields of the class.  Make sure your identity class has the same primary keys as your persistent type, including pk field types. Mismatched property: "team"
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.validateAppIdClassPKs(ClassMetaData.java:2216)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.validateAppIdClass(ClassMetaData.java:2090)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.validateIdentity(ClassMetaData.java:2026)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.validateMeta(ClassMetaData.java:1938)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.resolve(ClassMetaData.java:1799)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processBuffer(MetaDataRepository.java:822)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolveMeta(MetaDataRepository.java:719)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:643)
    ... 19 more
NestedThrowables:
<openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Attempt to map "model.Player.team" failed: the owning entity is not mapped.
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingInfo.assertTable(MappingInfo.java:628)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingInfo.createForeignKey(MappingInfo.java:1079)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ValueMappingInfo.getTypeJoin(ValueMappingInfo.java:115)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ValueMappingInfo.getTypeJoin(ValueMappingInfo.java:92)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.RelationFieldStrategy.map(RelationFieldStrategy.java:167)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.setStrategy(FieldMapping.java:146)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.RuntimeStrategyInstaller.installStrategy(RuntimeStrategyInstaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolveMapping(FieldMapping.java:496)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolve(FieldMapping.java:461)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.RelationToManyInverseKeyFieldStrategy.map(RelationToManyInverseKeyFieldStrategy.java:135)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.strats.RelationCollectionInverseKeyFieldStrategy.map(RelationCollectionInverseKeyFieldStrategy.java:95)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.setStrategy(FieldMapping.java:146)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.RuntimeStrategyInstaller.installStrategy(RuntimeStrategyInstaller.java:82)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolveMapping(FieldMapping.java:496)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.FieldMapping.resolve(FieldMapping.java:461)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ClassMapping.resolveMapping(ClassMapping.java:854)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData.resolve(ClassMetaData.java:1802)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.processBuffer(MetaDataRepository.java:822)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolveMapping(MetaDataRepository.java:777)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:657)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:411)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:384)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolveMeta(MetaDataRepository.java:714)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.resolve(MetaDataRepository.java:643)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaDataInternal(MetaDataRepository.java:411)
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.MetaDataRepository.getMetaData(MetaDataRepository.java:384)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingRepository.getMapping(MappingRepository.java:355)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.getMapping(MappingTool.java:682)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.buildSchema(MappingTool.java:754)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.MappingTool.run(MappingTool.java:652)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.synchronizeMappings(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:164)
    at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCBrokerFactory.newBrokerImpl(JDBCBrokerFactory.java:122)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.AbstractBrokerFactory.newBroker(AbstractBrokerFactory.java:209)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBrokerFactory.newBroker(DelegatingBrokerFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:227)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:154)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:60)
    at main.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

I know why I get this, but I cant fix it.
Can someone help me?

There is no problem, when I use a generated primary key (maybe long id) without IdClass.
But I need the IdClass.

Best Regards
Veote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess:

```
public class PlayerId {
    private String nickname;
    private Team team;  -> this should be "name" to match the Id in the class Team.

...

}
```

It's easier to use @EmbeddedId in this case I think.  See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/

The simple example from the site:

```
@Entity
class User {
  @EmbeddedId
  @AttributeOverride(name="firstName", column=@Column(name="fld_firstname")
  UserId id;

  Integer age;
}

@Embeddable
class UserId implements Serializable {
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
}
```

I would also remove Team from the class PlayerId, that doesn't seem a logical design choice at first sight.

Comment: When I change Team to String (name) then I get another Exception: Exception in thread "main" <openjpa-2.2.0-r422266:1244990 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The type of field "model.Player.team" isn't supported by declared persistence strategy "ManyToOne".  Please choose a different strategy.

Comment: No, you don't have to change the type, just the variable name has to match.  So  Team name in both classes Team and PlayerId.

Also, I don't think you have to use @Id, if you already use @ IdClass

Comment: When I change private Team team to private Team name I get the same Exceptions... When I remove the @Id annotation then I get the Exception, that I did not have declared any primary key...

Comment: Ok, maybe I should say that I want to implement a snowflake schema. So I want to use the PK from some Entities as FK and PK at once in my "Player" Entity. Maybe I chose a bad example

Comment: Maybe it's a little bit too complex for Hibernate to use Team as an Id: @Id
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;

Comment: Do you know another way without JPA2.0?

Comment: Yes, with EmbeddedId like I posted in the update in my answer. But you'll have to modify your design a bit. No Team in PlayerId (the Embeddable type)

Comment: But as I already said, I need the the primary Key of Team as Foreign Key and Primary Key at once in Player -> look at snowflake schema: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowflake_schema

Comment: I would rather continue this discussion in chat, but it's not possible because you don't have enough reputation unfortunately.
In this example ( http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/SetIdClassforCompoundKey.htm ) it says that the IdClass must be Serializable.  Maybe you can try that.

Comment: Oh I forgot this, but nothing new when I add Serializable :(

Comment: Still the same exception, because I really can't see anything wrong?

Comment: Yeah still the same. Can i map the oneToMany relation to the EmbeddedID?

Comment: I suggest you read this section to search another solution: 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-identifier
The Hibernate team suggests to modify your model design apparently. Greets

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem you had, and found my solution here:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/2.0/DerivedIdentifiers

You should't add the entity in your idClass, but the id of your entity. So try

```
public class PlayerId {
   private String nickname;
   private String team;

   ...
}
```