# Cannot use an @IdClass attribute for a @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a `Gfh_i18n` entity, with a composite key (`@IdClass`):

```
@Entity @IdClass(es.caib.gesma.petcom.data.entity.id.Gfh_i18n_id.class)
public class Gfh_i18n implements Serializable {

  @Id @Column(length=10, nullable = false)
  private String localeId = null;

  @Id <-- This is the attribute causing issues
  private Gfh gfh = null;
  ....
}
```

And the id class

```
public class Gfh_i18n_id implements Serializable {
  private String localeId = null;
  private Gfh gfh = null;
  ...
}
```

As this is written, this works. The issue is that I also have a `Gfh` class which will have a `@OneToMany` relationship to `Gfh_i18n`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="gfh")
@MapKey(name="localeId")
private Map<String, Gfh_i18n> descriptions = null;
```

Using Eclipse Dali, this gives me the following error:

```
 In attribute 'descriptions', the "mapped by" attribute 'gfh' has an invalid mapping type for this relationship.
```

If I just try to do, in `Gfh_1i8n`

```
@Id @ManyToOne
private Gfh gfh = null;
```

it solves the previous error but gives one in `Gfh_i18n`, stating that

```
The attribute matching the ID class attribute gfh does not have the correct type es.caib.gesma.petcom.data.entity.Gfh
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617859/jpa-map-manytoone-relation-with-idclass-persistence-argumentexception) is similar to mine, but I do not fully understand why I should be using `@EmbeddedId` (or if there is some way to use `@IdClass` with `@ManyToOne`).

I am using JPA 2.0 over Hibernate (JBoss 6.1)

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are dealing with a "derived identity" (described in the JPA 2.0 spec, section 2.4.1).

You need to change your ID class so the field corresponding to the "parent" entity field in the "child" entity (in your case `gfh`) has a type that corresponds to either the "parent" entity's single `@Id` field (e.g. `String`) or, if the "parent" entity uses an `IdClass`, the `IdClass` (e.g. `Gfh_id`).

In `Gfh_1i8n`, you should declare `gfh` like this:

```
@Id @ManyToOne
private Gfh gfh = null;
```

Assuming `GFH` has a single `@Id` field of type `String`, your ID class should look like this:

```
public class Gfh_i18n_id implements Serializable {
  private String localeId = null;
  private String gfh = null;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thans for your answer, but I have already tried that. When creating the table, I get an exception because the DDL is `create table Gfh_i18n (localeId varchar(10) not null, description varchar(50) null, gfh_id varchar(10) null, primary key (gfh_id, localeId))`. As it marks `gfh_id` as `null`, it cannot create the primary key. Tried marking `optional=false`, same result, and I cannot use `@Column` together with `@ManyToOne`. So far the only workaround has been using an `EmbeddedId` instead of `IdClass`, but I find it strange that I cannot use directly the `IdClass`.

Comment: Ok, I did read your documentation and find that it supported your claims too closely, so I have been doing tests and it seems a bug with JBoss6.1 Hibernate (3.6.6). Using 3.6.10 in a standalone program brought the same problem; using 4.1.8 in the same program worked fine.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me using EclipseLink. In my case, the single @Id-type was an int.