# Error using Hibernate 4.1.8 in JBoss 6.1 against SQLServer

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, jboss6.x

As a result of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682837/cannot-use-an-idclass-attribute-for-a-manytoone-relationship), I found a bug in Hibernate 3.6.x that was solved in 4.1.8. I have "upgraded" my JBoss 6.1 by deleting the hibernate libraries from common/lib and replacing with the new ones.

More concretely, I did delete:

- hibernate-commons-annotations.jar (replaced by hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final.jar)
- hibernate-core.jar (replaced by hibernate-core-4.1.8.Final.jar)
- hibernate-entitymanager.jar (replaced by hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.8.Final.jar)
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api.jar (replaced by hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar)

I did keep `hibernate-validator.jar` and `hibernate-validator-legacy.jar` as I didn't find a likely sustitute for them.

Now, the server starts without complaining but when it tries to map an Entity with a `boolean` attribute, it is trying to create a `boolean` field in SQLServer 2008 (which uses the type `bit`), causing that those tables are not created. Tables without `boolean` attributes do work right, though.

What I am doing wrong? My `persistence.xml` which worked fine prior to the upgrade has not been changed, and I don't find a reference to a new SQLServer dialect, so I am assuming my upgrade process was botched and I left something out. Any suggestions?

Just for the record, I am using JBoss6.1, JPA2.0 on top of Hibernate and SQL Server Express 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the annotation for your boolean fields try specifying a `columnDefinition`.

```
@Column(name="IS_APPROVED", columnDefinition="bit")
private boolean isApproved;
```

Comment: Ok, this has worked, thanks (so far I can only test the table creation process). Anyway I think it is a workaround; as this solution binds my application to SQLServer in the code and so I am losing some advantages of JPA. I will wait for a more "standard" answer (if that exists) before accepting this answer.

Comment: @Sjuan76 Maybe you will get a better answer, but its always nice to know there is a solution.  Best of luck!

Comment: I guess I'll try to move to JBoss 7.1