# Composite key using two related entity

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

---

Class A that has one to many relation with class C.

---

Class B that has one to many relation with class C.

---

I need the primary key of C to be composed of the primary key of both A and B.
I have tried to make a classId that has two object of A and B 
then I have added objects of A and B in C and added the `@id` annotation above both of them.
but I get a compilation error:

---

"the attribute matching the id class attribute A is not of type A" and the same of B.

---

Does it right to be worked in this way if not how to work it if yes how to solve the compilation error.
I am using eclipse link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682837/cannot-use-an-idclass-attribute-for-a-manytoone-relationship seems like it might solve this?